# Perl - assign a hash ref in a hash

Tags: perl, hash, reference

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::XS;
use YAML::XS;
my %data = ();
my $content = <<HERE;
{
  "name":"BLAHBLAH","contact":{"phone":"12345","twitter":"BLAHBLAH"},
  "location": {"address":"NOTTELLING","lat":10,"lng":10,"postalCode":"1234",
  "city":"BLAH","state":"BLAH","country":"BLAH"},
  "categories":[{"id":"BLAH","name":"BLAH"}]
}
HERE

my $id = "name1";

sub function {
    my ( $id, $data, $content ) = @_;
    my %data = %$data;
    my $out = decode_json($content);
    say "out:", Dump $out;
    $data{$id} = $out;
}

function( $id, \%data, $content );
say "data:", Dump %data;
```

This doesn't work as the way I expected. Can you please tell me why and how it will work?

Comment: You should not correct the code in your question as the answers are not reasonable if you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you're not finding anything in the package-scoped `%data` (the one defined just after `use YAML::XS`) is because you're creating a brand-new and completely independent `%data` inside of `function` with the line

```
my %data = %$data;
```

This creates a new hash and copies the contents of the hash referenced by `$data` into it.

Try this instead:

```
sub function {
  my ($id, $data, $content) = @_;
  my $out = decode_json($content);
  say "out:", Dump $out;
  $data->{$id} = $out;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> "This doesn't work as the way i expected."

What were you expecting?  Let's step through the errors:

1) `date` != `data`

2) `$content=~m!(,*)!` will leave `$1` empty, since `$content` doesn't contain any commas.

3) `decode_json($1)` will throw a runtime error, since `$1` is empty and `decode_json()` **can only be applied to a properly formatted JSON string.**

4) `$id` is not defined.

> "Can you please tell me why and how it will work?"

It won't work, if that isn't clear yet.  *There are more errors than code there.*

> "how do I assign a hash ref into hash?"

Use the `\` unary reference operator, eg:

```
my %h = ();

my %h2 = (
    a => 10
);

$h{h2} = \%h2;

print $h{h2}->{a};
```

You can also declare a scalar (`$`) as a reference to an **anonymous** (unnamed) hash; here `$hr` is a reference, the hash itself has no symbol or name associated with it:

```
my $hr = {
    n => 42
};

# as an existing hash member:

$h{h3} = {
    x => 666,
    # some other examples:
    hr => \%h2,
    hr2 => {
        x => 1024
    }    
};
```

Notice curly braces `{}` used in the declaration instead of `()`.  When you are nesting (anonymous) hashes as with `hr2`, always use that form.

If you search for *perl hash tutorial* you'll find more in-depth things.

Comment: Hey goldilocks, I apologize for my silly typos. I just made up everything in this question. hope now it is more understandable. My question is still that, how do I assign a hash ref into hash? Many thanks.

Comment: `$hash{one} = \%h;` this element of hash, which assign ref to another hash.

Comment: @IvanWang: I added some examples, see above.

Comment: also you can do this: `%hash=\%hash;` this statement create an key `SCALAR{\d+}` and value of this key in hash will be `undef`

Comment: do you mind to come back and check my codes again, because I just did the third time correction. I promise I really check everything this time. And I fixed all my stupid typos. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo:

```
function($id,/%data,$content);
```

must be

```
function($id,\%data,$content);
```

and $content is not a reference to %data hash, so in your function you should do:

```
my %data=%$data;  # in place of "my %content=%$content;"
```

Comment: do you mind to come back and check my codes again, because I just did the third time correction. I promise I really check everything this time. And I fixed all my stupid typos. Please help.